# How do you dynamically add an ending anchor (</a>) tag?

Tags: anchor, document.write

I am looking for a better way than document.write to insert an ending  tag into my code.  The reason for this is to close the tag depending on screen resolution with a mobile site.  The idea being that on a mobile device the excerpt of the text is clickable and will take you to the full article, however on a desktop it will not be clickable.  I have this working as desired using document.write however the code will not validate.  I am looking for a way to do this and have a validated code.   Here is what I have so far, thanks for any help you can provide.

```
<script>
if (screen && screen.width > 1024) document.write('</a>');
</script>

<script>
if (screen && screen.width <= 1024)
document.write('</a>');
</script>
```

Comment: you'd probably be better off outputting an `<a></a>` around the full text, then use a `<span>` to hide the bits that shouldn't be shown on the smaller screens. e.g. `<a>normal text<span>don't show this</span></a>` then toggle the visibility of the span depending on the screen parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery.

use `$('divID').append('<a>');`

Comment: not doing to work. that'll just append an empty `<a></a>` tag set. OP's opened the `<a>` outside of normal DOM operations, and now needs to close it.

Comment: Yes. I suggest to add something at the bottom using the Append. The intent is to append instead of write.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help so far.  Marc B is correct I only need to output the closing `</a>`  However as to your above reply Marc, It's not the case that I need to show/hide content based on screen size, in this case the content will always be visible.  What I am trying to do is change whether just the title of the post is hyperlinked (larger screens), or the text is also hyperlinked (mobile).  The site in question is http://rockbassnow.com.  It is also a Wordpress theme if that changes some possible solutions.